# Can I install a 2018 Subaru Forester bumper onto my 2016 Subaru Forester?

Tags: subaru, body, tail-lights, forester

Can I install a 2018 Subaru Forester bumper onto my 2016 Subaru Forester? I like the style and it looks more sporty. Also, can I install the 2017-18 tail lights for the same car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I can't tell you for sure, but since they are of the same generation, there's a *very good* chance it will. The fourth gen goes from 2013-2018. There may be more which would have to be changed for it to line up, but rather these parts should most likely attach to body mounting points.

Comment: https://www.subaruforester.org/

Answer (score 0):

If the tail lights are the same size, shape and depth, then probably yes, if they are different as in size, shape or depth then probably no... unless you want to do some serious bodywork modification.